# Display an Alert popup when application is receiving an Apple Push Notification in iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I am creating a `Chat` kind of iPhone application using `Apple push notification services`. APN's is working fine and i am getting `notification` when user is receiving new message. So, i have set one `Toast` pop up in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` of my `App Delegate` class. The problem is, i am getting Toast pop up in every `View Controller` screen because i have added Toast on my `main window` itself. but can you please help me that how can i hide this `Toast` pop up from one of my `Chat List View Controller` screen. How can i check which `View Controller` is loaded currently on my window view, when application is in `foreground`?

**here is my code :**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo
{
    if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive ){

        NSString  *personName = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"user_name"];
        NSString *meassge = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"New message from %@.", personName];

        [[self window] makeToast:meassge duration:1.0 position:@"center"];


        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadTheTable" object:nil];
    } 

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare below methods in AppDelegate.m

```
  - (UIViewController*)topViewController {
     return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
}

- (UIViewController*)topViewControllerWithRootViewController:(UIViewController*)rootViewController {
     if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {
        UITabBarController* tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)rootViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:tabBarController.selectedViewController];
     } else if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
     UINavigationController* navigationController = (UINavigationController*)rootViewController;
     return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:navigationController.visibleViewController];
     } else if (rootViewController.presentedViewController) {
    UIViewController* presentedViewController = rootViewController.presentedViewController;
    return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:presentedViewController];
    } else {
    return rootViewController;
    }
  }

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo
 {
  if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive ){

    NSString  *personName = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"user_name"];
    NSString *meassge = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"New message from %@.", personName];
    if(![[self topViewController] isKindOfClass:[ChatListViewController class]])//ChatListViewController is your viewcontroller
        [[self window] makeToast:meassge duration:1.0 position:@"center"];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadTheTable" object:nil];
  } 

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

}

Comment: @RamyaIt's not working, i have tried your code. Still i am getting toast on my ChatListViewController class.

Comment: Please check once topViewController returning ChatListViewController or not by placing NSLog(@"top view controller is %@",[self topViewController]); before if condition

Comment: I am getting [self topViewController] as SWRevealViewController in my console. Actually i am presenting my ChatListViewController by using SWRevealViewController.

Comment: change else part with the below code    else if (rootViewController.presentedViewController) {
    UIViewController* presentedViewController = [rootViewController.presentedViewController 
childViewControllers] lastObject];
    return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:presentedViewController];
    }

Comment: Hey thanks alot bro for giving me time, now using your code i am comparing SWRevealViewController class title and hiding popup from  ChatListViewController class using if ([[self topViewController].title isEqualToString:@"NotifificationType"]). It's working fine now. Thanks